# writing output to a file from a procedure in sqlplus - SPOOL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Due to being unable to use UTL_FILE (lack of privileges, changing that not gonna happen :/) I'm messing with using SPOOL to get output from my procedure to a CSV file. I have serveroutput set to 'on', procedure uses DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.
I'm trying to wrap this in an sql file.

The part I'm having problems with:

```
spool output.csv
/
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
... 
END;
/
spool off
quit
/
```

Problem is, this way the whole block lands in my output file, followed by the output, while I would like just the output.

I have alternatively tried to use a function with the PIPELINED keyword and output the rows via PIPE ROW method, hoping the SELECT * FROM TABLE () syntax would help me out, but it's the same story.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/320407

Comment: This example has the same problem I have - if you copy/paste the block from the last post and check the output file, you will notice what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what was the issue. The standard SQL PLUS switches work great ( trimspool, termout, sqlprompt, etc) however you MUST use SQL Plus DIRECTLY. As in, DO NOT USE Oracle SQL Developer for that.
Those damn worksheets you open inside it just seem to behave differently in SQL Plus related stuff.
I moved everything I was doing to the machine I was connecting to with SQL Developer, logged to SQL Plus directly, executed my .sql script from the command line and voila! a clean .csv file.